# C2666: Visual Studio can't choose an appropriate overload of a function

Tags: c++

I have 2 declarations

```
void log::Category::Log(bool,const log::Priority &,const char *,...) 
void log::Category::Log(const log::Priority &,const char *,...)
```

then I call

```
m_log.Log(log::Priority::PRI_DEBUG, "%s", pszStr);
```

`log::Priority` is `enum`.

Why compiler matches both?

Comment: What are the full function signatures of each (where you wrote `...`)? And what is the exact compiler error?

Comment: What is `log::Priority`? Is it a class with an (implicit) constructor that takes a `const char *` parameter?

Comment: What is `log::Priority::PRI_DEBUG`?

Comment: @CoryKramer, `...` means `Log` is a variadic function. Error is C2666, and it says it can't decide which function to choose.

Comment: Can you show the definition of Priority?

Comment: @alexander.sivak Oh gotcha, I didn't know if your functions were variadic, or you left `...` as pseudo-code for arguments you thought were irrelevant for the example

Comment: Not the reason of the ambiguity, but if `log::Priority` is an `enum`, you should not pass it by reference but simply or more efficiently by value.

Comment: @prapin, I can't change signatures.

Comment: What's the full error message (including related notes) that the compiler gives you?

Comment: This example is not complete, so its impossible to know why it doesn't work. [Seems just fine to me.](https://godbolt.org/z/GdW7rT)

Comment: @user2407038 Tell me what else you require to answer the question.

Comment: @alexander.sivak A complete example is one which is a full program which any reader can (try to) compile and see the error you're getting. Compiler version, exact error message from your compiler helps as well.